# Python-How to bin positive and negative values to get counts for time series plot

Tags: python, time-series

I'm trying to recreate a time-series plot similar to the one below (not including the 'HLMA Flashes' data)

[image]

This is what my datafile looks like, the polarity is in the "charge" column. I used pandas to load in the file and set up the table on jupyter notebook. The value  of the charge does not matter, only whether it is positive or negative.

[image]

Once I get the count of the total/negative/positives, I know how to plot this against time, but I'm not sure how to approach binning to get the counts (or whatever is needed) to make the time series. Preferably I need this in 5-minute bin periods during the timeframe of my dataframe (0000-07000 UTC). Apologies if this question is worded poorly, but any leads would be appreciated.

Link to .txt file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13XEc74LO3cZQhylAdSfhLeUn7GFgtiKT/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what I believe you are asking:

```py
df2 = ( pd.DataFrame( {
    'Datetime' : pd.to_datetime(df.agg(lambda x: f"{x['Date']} {x['Time']}", axis=1)),
    'Neg': df.Charge < 0,
    'Pos': df.Charge > 0,
    'Tot': [1] * len(df)} ) )
df2['minutes'] = (df2.Datetime.dt.hour * 60 + df2.Datetime.dt.minute) // 5 * 5
df3 = df2[['minutes','Neg','Pos','Tot']].groupby('minutes').sum()
```

Output:

```
         Neg  Pos  Tot
minutes
45         0    1    1
55         0    1    1
65         0    2    2
85         0    2    2
90         0    2    2
95         0    1    1
100        0    3    3
105        1    4    5
110        2   11   13
115        0   10   10
120        0    6    6
125        1   13   14
130        3   70   73
135        2   20   22
140        1    5    6
165        0    2    2
170        3    1    4
175        2    5    7
180        2   12   14
185        3   26   29
190        1   11   12
195        0    4    4
200        1   14   15
205        1    4    5
210        0    1    1
215        0    1    1
220        0    1    1
225        3    0    3
230        1    5    6
235        0    4    4
240        1    2    3
245        0    3    3
260        0    1    1
265        0    1    1
```

Explanation:

- create a 'Datetime' column from 'Date' and 'Time' columns using `to_datetime()`
- create `Neg` and `Pos` columns based on sign of `Charge`, and create `Tot` column equal to `1` for each row
- create `minutes` column to bin the rows into 5 minute intervals
- use `groupby()` and `sum()` to aggregate `Neg`, `Pos` and `Tot` for each interval with at least one row.

Comment: Thanks! The df3 makes sense and looks good to me but I’m having trouble getting the time-series to work. I was simply trying 

‘ 
ax.plot(df3['minutes'], df3['Tot'], color='black', label='Total') #total
ax.plot(df3['minutes'], df3['Pos'], color='red', label='Positive') #positive
ax.plot(df3['minutes'], df3['Neg'], color='blue', label='Negative') #negative
‘ 

But think my x axis is still giving me issues. Could it be that even though this is from 0-7UTC there isn’t 5-min bins with counts throughout the entire time period? Or some other issue?

Comment: I was able to get the time-series made by resetting the index for df3 and calling that for my x-axis. but since it's using the converted 5-min bin periods, i'm not sure how to make the time-range for my axis to be 00-07UTC (including the time periods where there wasn't any lightning recorded). I tried using ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,7,1)) but getting shape errors obviously. @constantstranger